# How do I dynamically resize the JFrame to include JPanel with varying content size?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

How do I make my `JFrame` match the size of the `JPanel` which holds the dynamically sized content?

I have created two simple class snippets if anyone could guide me through them.

### Class1 : CanvasExample.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class CanvasExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanelEx dataOut = new JPanelEx();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Title!");
                f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,100));
                f.getContentPane().add(dataOut);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Class 2:  JPanelEx.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPanelEx extends JPanel {
   public JPanelEx() {
         super(new FlowLayout());
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        g.drawString("Hello1", 10, 10);
        g.drawString("Hello2", 10, 30);
        g.drawString("Hello3", 10, 50);
        g.drawString("Hello4", 10, 70);
        g.drawString("Hello5", 10, 90);
        g.drawString("Hello6", 10, 110);
        g.drawString("Hello7", 10, 130);
        g.drawString("Hello8", 10, 150);
        g.drawString("Hello9", 10, 170);
        g.drawString("Hello10", 10, 190);
        g.dispose();
  }
}
```

#### Current Output :

[image: Current Output]

#### Expected Output :

[image: Expected Output]

I understand similar question might have been asked many times but I scanned through and couldn't get a clear solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That really looks like the custom painting should be replaced with a `JList`.

Comment: If it were actual `Shape` or `Area` objects we could add them all together and bet the bounding box, then return a preferred size based on that box.  Though text can be converted to a `GlyphVector` that in turn can be converted to an `Area`, I'd tend to just use a list for this as described in my 1st comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I understand but I am supposed to remain restricted to using the drawstring since there is processing involved on those strings, which is drawn anywhere on the JPanel.

Comment: @Zeus This will require to design some kind of "virtual" layout manager, which can keep track of where each `String` should be, this will make it easier to perform the required calculations to determine the preferred size of your component...

Comment: *"restricted to using the drawstring since there is processing involved on those strings, which are drawn all over the Panel."*  So are you saying that using a `GlyphVector` is ruled out?  It can do everything that `drawString` can, and more, but negates the need for it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I know is archaic but I had to stick to it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JPanelEx` will need to provide size hints to allow the layout management system to determine how best the component should be laid out and the amount of space the content needs

Also, don't call `dispose` on `Graphics` contexts you didn't create!

As an example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JPanelEx());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class JPanelEx extends JPanel {

        private int numElements = 10;

        public JPanelEx() {
            super(new FlowLayout());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            int width = 0;
            int height = fm.getHeight() * numElements;
            for (int index = 0; index < numElements; index++) {
                width = Math.max(width, fm.stringWidth("Hello" + index));
            }

            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            for (int index = 0; index < numElements; index++) {
                g.drawString("Hello" + index, x, y + fm.getAscent());
                y += fm.getHeight();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details about the layout manager API

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using your suggestion to get the Font Metrics on each string and calculating the height.